# commands.bot not callable

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make my first discord bot and im following a beginner tutorial but even after doing all the things said in the video i still get this error and i have no idea what it means

error:

```
line 4, in <module>
    bot = commands.bot(command_prefix=".")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.bot(command_prefix=".")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready!")

bot.run("id here")
```

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You have made a typo, you should be doing `commands.Bot` instead of `commands.bot`.
This error means that you're calling a module, and it is not callable in this situation, by callable, it's how you call functions `func()`.

Comment: @aph That seemed to fix it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is a typo you've made

line 4 should be like this:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
```

Docs for `discord.ext.commands.Bot` found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bot)

## Complete Solution

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready!")

bot.run("token here")
```

### Config files

I would also suggest you not hardcode tokens directly in scripts like this, since they should always be kept secret, it can be dangerous to leak your token.
You can use python `JSON` lib and have the token in a `config.json` file, or a `YAML` file, or you can set the token as an Environmental variable.